# How to cancel alarms?

Tags: android

I have the following situation.

I need to set many alarms to start the same Activity at different specific dates.

In order to accomplish this, I obviously use an AlarmManager.

Since the PendingIntents given to the AlarmManager are all equivalent, in order to have Android create all of them (and not just 1) I use a different `requestCode` to differentate among them.

All of this works fine, all alarms are created correctly.

**The point is that sometimes I have to cancel them!**

**If I do not do it with the same `requestCode` the AlarmManager does not cancel them.**

It is very difficult to retrieve the original `requestCode` in the code, since they are created at runtime at different moments/days...

Any suggestion on how to address this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right approach, as the only way I know to cancel the alarms would be cancel the pending intents with the same `requestCode`, however your issue is retrieving the same request codes made at run time. You would have to store these codes some how either by SQLite, or shared preferences perhaps to have them stored on the device then retrieve them as needed. Alternatively you could pass the `requestCode` as a `bundle` in the intent and then cancel it immediately after it fires off, or when ever through the alarms life cycle you choose. Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: thanks kabuto178 I am afraid I need to store them somewhere... I hope someone has some kind of magic hack to avoid this... :-)

Comment: Since Alarms seems to a significant API you use, i would highly recommend using SQLite as it would be easier to play with and would be more cleaner and can have quite a number of Alarms saved.

Comment: You do not wish to use `SQLite` or passing the request code in the intent as I suggested?